# Angular 6 создать тег с сожержимой

Tags: angular5

У меня есть условия где после `id="confirm_Password"` создаю или удаляю элемент `span` с содержимой, но это сделано с помощью `Jquery`, можете помощь его преобразовать в чистый `typescript`

```
if (data['password'] == data['confirm_Password']) {
                    $('.confirm_Password_message').remove();
                } else {

                     $('<span class="confirm_Password_message">Passwords do not match</span>').insertAfter($('#confirm_Password'));
                }
```

**form**

```
config: FieldConfig[] = [
        {
            type: 'textarea',
            label: 'Description',
            name: 'description',
            placeholder: 'Description',
            value: '',
            validation: [
                {
                    name: 'required',
                    validator: Validators.required,
                    message: 'Description Required'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            type: 'checkbox',
            label: 'Status',
            name: 'status',
            value: ''
        },
        {
            label: 'Submit',
            name: 'submit',
            type: 'button',
        }
    ];
```

**form html**

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <app-dynamic-form #form="appDynamicForm" (submit)="formSubmitted($event)" [config]="config"></app-dynamic-form>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default float-right mr-2"  (click)="hideModal()">Close</button>
      </div>
```

Comment: сообщение для description - показывается? если да, то нужно делать по аналогии и добавить свой валидатор для нужного поля

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реактивные формы позволяют писать кастомную валидацию, свой компонент вы не показали, поэтому я приведу вам небольшой пример:

```
public form = new FormGroup({
    passwords: new FormGroup({
        password: new FormControl(null),
        confirmedPassword: new FormControl(null)
    }, {
        validators: [
            (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
                const password = control.get('password').value;
                const confirmedPassword = control.get('confirmedPassword').value;

                if (password === confirmedPassword) {
                    return null;
                }

                return {
                    passwordsMissmatch: true
                };
            }
        ]
    })
});

public get passwordsMissmatch(): boolean {
    return this.form.get('passwords').hasError('passwordsMissmatch');
}
```

Если вы создаете компонент вручную через `ComponentFactoryResolver`, то вы можете получить это свойство из инстанса:

```
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory...
const componentRef: ComponentRef<SomeComponent> = factory.create(this.injector);
console.log(componentRef.instance.passwordsMissmatch);
```

Или слушать изменение формы:

```
const { instance } = componentRef;

instance.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(instance.passwordsMissmatch);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот простое решение вашей задачи с использованием "template reference variables"
:

```
<input #password (keyup)="0">
<input #confirmPassword (keyup)="0" >
<span *ngIf="password.value !== confirmPassword.value">Passwords do not match</span>
```

Comment: Да, но `input` я создаю в `typescript`, нужно чтобы сообщения тоже создать через `typescript`

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, в чем заключается причина создания input в typescript

Comment: У меня angular dynamic form https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms

Comment: @AraChinaryan, в чем принципиальная разница между инпутом и спаном в данном случае?

Comment: @Grundy так как у меня почти нету `html` кода, я нее могу просто взять и в `html` написать `span` и `*ngIf`, можно только в `typescript`, но создал через `Jquery` я тоже не восторге от этой структуры, хочу понять `typescript` дает мне такие возможности (создать и удалять элемент) как `Jquery`, если нет буду это оставлять, я просто новичок.

Comment: @AraChinaryan, добавь **минимальный** пример твоего кода, как ты с инпутом работаешь

Comment: @Grundy добавил, а источник [тут](https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms)